# Meaning of $\overline{A} + \overline{B}$ in Rudin's functional analysis book?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to make sure I understand the notation here as I have not come across it before.

Say we have a topological vector space $X = \mathbb{R}$.

And let $A = \overline{A} = [1, 2]$, $B = \overline{B} = [3, 5]$.

Then it seems to me that we are supposed are supposed to 'pick' either $\overline{A}$ or $\overline{B}$, say we pick $\overline{A}$, and then we add all $x \in \overline{B}$ to $A$ which gives us $\overline{A} + \overline{B} = [4, 7]$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. From the bottom of p.5 of Rudin's book:

> [image]